# Project can't see main Maven eclipse mockito

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mockito, program-entry-point

I've got quite a bit of code and for some reason it can't see the main. So, I started from scratch and still getting that it can't see the main.  Pricing is the original project and InsurancePricer is the new one.  [image]

```
package com.pricing.pricer;

import com.pricing.model.Consumer;

public class InsurancePricing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world.");
    }   
}
```

When I run Maven clean install it runs the tests and passes the tests but when I want it to just run the program I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.mockito.asm.util.ASMifierClassVisitor

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here's my pom in case it helps figure out what's going on.

Comment: It's not clear at all what is your problem. What do you mean with "it can't see the Main"? Are you trying to run main of InsurancePricing in Eclipse? Why do you have mockito in the title?

Comment: I added some details to the question not realizing I hadn't added them.

Comment: Do you use any Mockito classes in your non-test classes (you shouldn't be, check all the import lines)? And is your Mockito dependency set to `test` scope in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Not using mockito in anything other than test class and yes it is scoped to test in the pom file.  That's the strange part. I created a clean project with the infrastructure only and getting the same thing.

Comment: The whole stack trace might help. Or is it that you run it on the cmd line with `java` and get only that row?

Comment: I get only that row.

Comment: HOW do you run the program? Maven run? Eclipse run button? Maven install and then java -jar? What command do you use?

Comment: Run as Java Application @Florian schaetz

Comment: One of the problems with Eclipse is, that it's not actually able to handle the multiple classpaths of maven (run/test), sometimes it gets confused. Typical symptom  would be stuff running fine with maven but strange classpath problems with eclipse. Could be that. Sometimes switching of the workspace resolution works (but then you have to rebuild the dependencies manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problems seems to be related to your `MANIFEST.MF` in jar file if it occurs only when running jar.

Check how `MANIFEST.MF` is built and value of param `Main-Class` is it perhaps *org.mockito.asm.util.ASMifierClassVisitor*

Or do you perhaps have main class defined somewhere else? What it is?

You can also try if this in cmd line

`java -cp YOUR.JAR com.pricing.pricer.InsurancePricing` works.

Comment: I get the same thing. Error: Could not find or load main class com.pricing.pricer.InsurancePricing

Comment: it has been awhile since used java  on cmd let me see again... how about the manifest if you unzip jar and check it ?

Comment: @April_Nara check the update for cmd  and the MANIFEST.MF how it is done / what it contains.

Comment: Just checked it.  It just has that the project was created with eclipse Maven Project and author.

Comment: So how do you run it? from eclipse run configuration or cmd line? I mean that the main class has to be declared somewhere.

Comment: I've been trying to get the Eclipse "Run As" -> "Java Application" to run it like I normally run a maven project without test cases. This is the first time I've had a project set-up that uses Maven and tests with a main.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158025/discussion-between-pirho-and-april-nara).